# Blank string in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to learn PySpark using a dataset I made with news articles.

I'm trying to get the most frequent words in the articles' titles.

The code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master('local[*]') \
    .appName("PySpark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.jars", "postgresql-42.3.6.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/newsscraper") \
    .option("dbtable", "articles") \
    .option("user", "root") \
    .option("password", "root") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .load()

df.printSchema()

from pyspark.sql.functions import split, explode, udf


import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
stoplist = stopwords.words('english')
stoplist += ['|','—','-','–'] # some common characters that appear in titles
stoplist += list(map(lambda x: x.capitalize(),stoplist))

df2 = df.withColumn('words',split(df['title'],' '))
df2 = df2.withColumn('words',explode(df2['words'])).select('words')
words = df2.filter(~(df2['words'].isin(stoplist)))

words.groupBy('words').count().orderBy('count',ascending = False).show()
```

The output is all good except for the first cell

```
+--------+-----+
|   words|count|
+--------+-----+
|        |  423|
|    says|  422|
|     New|  324|
| Ukraine|  312|
|shooting|  280|
|  school|  270|
|   Texas|  269|
|  review|  254|
|      US|  248|
|     new|  227|
|     gun|  204|
|   Biden|  202|
|  police|  179|
|      UK|  175|
|   could|  165|
|    U.S.|  163|
| Russian|  157|
|  Russia|  154|
|     say|  150|
|    Utah|  145|
+--------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

As you can see, it's invisible. I tried to use regex to filter all non-English words, like so:

```
clean_text = udf(lambda x: re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+?','',x))
...
df2 = df2.withColumn('words',clean_text(df2['words'])).select('words')
words = df2.filter(~(df2['words'].isin(stoplist)))
words = words.groupBy('words').count().orderBy('count',ascending = False)
words.show()
```

but then I got:

```
+--------+-----+
|   words|count|
+--------+-----+
|        | 3027|
|    says|  430|
|      US|  419|
| Ukraine|  366|
|shooting|  355|
|     New|  327|
|   Texas|  282|
|  school|  281|
|  review|  274|
|     new|  235|
|   Biden|  212|
|     gun|  210|
|     war|  203|
|      UK|  201|
|  police|  183|
|  Russia|  168|
|   could|  165|
|  Uvalde|  162|
| Russian|  159|
|    Utah|  152|
+--------+-----+
```

I don't know if there is a character in the titles themselves, or if pyspark's `split` function result in some weird behaviour.

How to filter that string out? Is there a way to know/see the unicode/string?

[CSV file](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/O2BrO54K#link) of the titles used.

Comment: Well, I kind of found a solution? instead of the last line, I used `words.where("words != ''").show()`

It works, but I still need an explanation of why `split` (or `explode`, I don't know which one caused the problem) returned an empty string in the first place (before I use the regex).

Comment: If string is like "abc def    " and then split will generate ["abc", "def", "", "", "", ""].

Comment: Do you have any further explanation of why does it do that?

Comment: you can try trimming the `title` field before splitting it -- `split(trim(col('title')),' ')`

Comment: It shows the same output with '' count 423. It looks like the empty strings don't come from trailing whitespaces, or the function `split` just pads the array with empty strings.